# How to make a "text editor" in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, text-editor

I would like to have a "NumericUpDown" and "DomainUpDown" that would change some text in a text file on a specified line.
Please help.

Example of what i need to edit:

```
"removePanelsModeSwitcher": true,
```

on this i need to edit true/false with "DomainUpDown"

and

```
"x": 235,
"y": -256,
```

on this need edit the numbers on this with "NumericUpDown"

Comment: What is this??! :) (-> smiley to prove that I am happy; apparently, being surprised by incoherence and trying to understand why the incoherent behaviour occurs at all might be misunderstood as being angry)

Comment: Plese, wait for solution..i will be find and reply

Comment: Is your `on this i need to edit true/false with "DomainUpDown"` `and` `on this need edit the numbers on this with "NumericUpDown"` a part of your code!? Remove it immediately or add an apostrophe ahead of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

```
    Dim x As String = Chr(34) & "x" & Chr(34) & ": "
    Dim FileName As String = "c:\some folder\path\data.txt"
    Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileName)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        If lines(i).StartsWith(x) Then
            lines(i) = x & NumericUpDown1.Value & ","
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FileName, lines)
```

Comment: But there may be many instances of( "x": 235,
 "y": -256,) how to look between lets say, lines 25-50 ?

Comment: If you want a specific line then simply access it with `lines(i)` where i is the zero-indexed line number...

Comment: If you need a specific set after a certain "header", then search for it first using a for loop like in my example.